# Wifi connection is excellent. No internet. All devices and laptops work except desktop with vista. Help please

Tags: windows-vista, internet, connection

Wifi is excellent. No internet access on desktop with Vista.  Devices and laptop work fine.  Wires are secure.  Please help.

Comment: Please give some more details. have you checked you firewall ?

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options here:

- Switching out the cat5 cable that connects the desktop to your router.
- Switch the port the cat5 cable is plugged into.
- Check the device manager on the desktop, you are looking at the network card, if there are yellow or red pings it is not functioning properly.
- In the device manager you can uninstall the network card.  Then reboot the PC, windows will detect new hardware and re-install the network card.

A more detailed question will help as well, I made several assumptions with my answer.